# PHP / Javascript create countdown between 2 times

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have many issues trying to think of how to create this script.

I currently have 2 variables :

```
$curHour = "15:25:00";
$endHour = "16:25:00";
```

I am struggling to find how to create a countdown specifcally between these times.

I would appreciate any help.

Greetings Glenn

Comment: First, find out how many seconds are between _now_ and `$endHour` then you can display that number in a countdown. Using JavaScript you can make it tick down dynamically. Your question is currently set up to request a full code solution, that's too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Glenn what do you think by saying: to create a countdown ?

Comment: @Glenn show some code, even if it does not work at all, demonstrate that you do not want that anyone else does it all for you, and you will get some help, on the contrary you will get negatives...

Comment: In your example difference between cur - end = 1 hour, you can use javascript setTimeout function, and each second decrement countdown 1 second. 1 hour = 60*60 = 3600 seconds. $("#countdown").html($("#countdown").html-1)

Comment: You have to start somewhere. PHP isn't a dynamic scripting language so you will have to use javascript if you want to display the timer in real time. Give it a try first and then we'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just finished in javascript, but the code seems a little long.
html:

```
<div id="process"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var process = document.getElementById('process');

var cur = '15:25:00';
var end = '16:25:00';

cur = cur.split(':');
end = end.split(':');
var x = parseInt(cur[0], 10)*3600+parseInt(cur[1], 10)*60+parseInt(cur[2], 10);
var y = parseInt(end[0], 10)*3600+parseInt(end[1], 10)*60+parseInt(end[2], 10);

showTime(y);
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    y--;
    showTime(y);
    if(y<=x){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);

function showTime(diff){
    var hour = parseInt(diff/3600, 10);
    var minute = parseInt((diff - hour*3600)/60, 10);
    var second = diff - hour*3600-minute*60;

    hour   = hour<10 ? '0'+hour : hour;
    minute = minute<10 ? '0'+minute : minute;
    second = second<10 ? '0'+second : second;

    var time = hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
    process.innerHTML = time;
}
```

Comment: Ty for the comment but couldnt get this to work the 2 times that are inputted without submitting a start form needs to show the time left between those 2 times

Comment: yes, I hava just tried, Anirban's solution so simplte and great

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below,

```
setInterval(function () {

    var end = <?php  echo strtotime('16:25:00')*1000;?>;//Javascriptcomapatible time
    var current = new Date().getTime(); //Current timestamp
    var seconds_left = (end - current) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    console.log(days + "d, " + hours + "h,"+ minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s");  

}, 1000);
```